# Question regarding fair ticket price for a game with 3 dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following exercise:

> Consider a game where three (fair) dice are rolled. You pay `$1` to
>   enter the game. If there are no sixes for the 3 rolls, you lose your
>   `$1` stake. If you obtain i sixes, i = 1,2,3, then you are paid `$i`
>   and have your stake returned (i.e. a profit of `$i`). Additionally,
>   the game also allows players to place a supplementary bet on the event
>   of 3 sixes with a payoff of `$y` for a `$1` stake if this happens.
>   Suppose you pay `$1` to enter the game, and you also place an
>   additional `$1` supplementary bet on the event of 3 sixes. What value
>   of `y` would make the game fair?

In one of the lectures, the professor taught us that:

```
E(X) is the fair ticket price for a game where the players win amount x with p(X)
```

So I thought I need to use `E(X) = 2` (`$1` for joining the basic game, `$1` for joining the supplementary game) to calculate `y`. However, in the explanatory note, the professor used `E(X) = 0` to calculate `y`.

Can you please tell me why `E(X) = 2` is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the expectation of what the house pays you back.  Your professor is calculating the expectation of the net-the house payback less the 2 you paid the house.  Each is correct.  You have to be careful which expectation you are calculating.